# Django add language code to url in html if condition

Tags: django, internationalization

I have a navbar that shows `active` when it is in the current section. I have internationalised the web so now the url includes the language code. How can I add the language code in the if condition below?

{% if '/{LANGUAGE_CODE}/accounts/dashboard/' == request.path %} active {% endif %}

webpage url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/accounts/dashboard

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

<aside class="col-md-3">
  <!--   SIDEBAR   -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item {% if '/{LANGUAGE_CODE}/accounts/dashboard/' == request.path %} active {% endif %}" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"> Dashboard </a>
[continues...]
```

I tried {{LANGUAGE_CODE}} and some pasting. Any ideas how to get the if condition working?

Comment: I think you can use `| format` template filter.

Comment: I am trying `{% if '/{{LANGUAGE_CODE | lower}}/accounts/dashboard/' == request.path %}` and other variants without success.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter to concatenate your strings and [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag to cache this complex variable. The result would look like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

<aside class="col-md-3">
  <!--   SIDEBAR   -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    {% with "/"|add:LANGUAGE_CODE|add:"/accounts/dashboard/" as dashboard_url %}
    <a class="list-group-item {% if dashboard_url == request.path %} active {% endif %}" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"> Dashboard </a>
    {% endwith %}
[continues...]
```